# What is wrong with this mysql query?

Tags: mysql, select, integer

Hai guys,

I ve tried a query and i dont know what is wrong with the select statement,when i execute this no records are returned...

**It seems rollid=3 is the prob records with rollid 3 are not fetched**,

```
select * from tbl_emp_personal_master where dEmp_id ='7'


dEmp_id is int
```

I even tried removing quotes from `'7' to 7` it didnt help[alt text http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/1901/mysqli.jpg](http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/1901/mysqli.jpg)

**when i repaired my table `repair table  tbl_emp_personal_master` it started to work**

Comment: are you sure there are any records in the table that matches the criteria?

Comment: @David ya there are records when i gave dEmp_name it gets the corresponding record

Comment: can you please show the data on your table

Comment: Curious to know the reason why this query went wrong. Found it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then in your 'tbl_emp_personal_master' there's no dEmp_id with the value '7'.

`select dEmp_id from tbl_emp_personal_master` query should tell you whether you have 7 value in the listed values in the result set. Check!

Answer (score 3):

The other answers suggesting:

```
select * from tbl_emp_personal_master where dEmp_id = 7
```

should work. If it doesn't, it means that the row doesn't exist in your database. Try:

```
select * from tbl_emp_personal_master where dEmp_id < 1000
```

and see if that returns any results.

Comment: i tried the second one it worked , i dont know it is very strange that it takes upto 6 empids but not 7

Comment: @Sarnya, are you saying that the "< 1000" version showed you employee number 7?

Comment: ya paxdiablo but i didnt get records when i give = symbol

Answer (score 3):

Let's try a little debugging. You say that

```
select * from tbl_emp_personal_master where dEmp_id = '7'
```

doesn't work, nor does:

```
select * from tbl_emp_personal_master where dEmp_id = 7
```

Then you should isolate what does work. Try each of the following:

```
select * from tbl_emp_personal_master where dEmp_id < 10   order by dEmp_id desc
select * from tbl_emp_personal_master where dEmp_id < 100  order by dEmp_id desc
select * from tbl_emp_personal_master where dEmp_id < 1000 order by dEmp_id desc
```

until you get some output, then have a look at the last few lines of each where you should find employee number 7.

If it's not there, then you *have* no such employee and that's your problem. If it *is* there, we're going to need some more investigation since your integer select of 7 should work fine in that case.

---

*Update:* Okay, with only 14 records, in the table, show us the output from:

```
select * from tbl_emp_personal_master order by dEmp_id
```

and we should be able to help from there.

Comment: @paxdiablo my table contains 14 records i can get records upto 6 th one but from 7 th icant get when i give a where condition

Comment: See the update. The table is tiny so, if you show us the whole thing, it should be easier to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @paxdiablo see the screen shot above

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from the 7.

Comment: You may want to "select * from tbl" to make sure that the id 7 actually exists...

Answer (score 1):

7 instead of '7'. You're trying to match an int field with a charatcer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by repairing my table `repair table tbl_emp_personal_master` . My query was executed. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: You could accept your **answer** so others can get benefitted.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is indeed that there is no record having the dEmp_id field set to 7.

```
  select * from tml_emp_personal_master where dEmp_id between 6 and 8
```

should allow to check this.

Regarding the enclosure of the field, it depends on your DBMS. Enclosing numeric values in MySQL is perfectly legal and even [recommended](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/security-guidelines.html) (cf chapter about SQL injections and numeric values).

Regarding what is *wrong*, it is generally recommended not to use **select *** but to list all required fields for performance and readability purposes.

Also, if the query is ran from a programming language, it is strongly adviced to use parameterized queries if available (for instance DBParameter in .Net, PDO in PHP etc).